# Show error message using validate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having difficulty displaying an error message on the screen.

I have a class called `Issue`, and this has several attachments.

No model/issue_attachment, 
I am checking the files to determine if they are supported. In the case that the file name are not supported I am displaying the number **1** on the screen (just for testing, I will improve).

Only it is not showing "LOL" on the screen. I know I can do the validation and display the error message on model/issue_attachment, but in this case I need to do so.

```
class IssueAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :issue, counter_cache: :attachments_count

  has_attached_file :attachment, :url => '/system/:issue_attachment_directory/:filename'

  validates_attachment_size :attachment, :less_than => 10.megabytes, :message =>    I18n.t('errors.messages.issue_attachment_file_size_html', :max => '10 MB')
  validate :suspitious_attachment


def suspitious_attachment
 if ends_with? '.bat', '.com', '.exe', '.src', '.cmd'
   1
 end
 1
end

private

def ends_with?(*args)
  args.each do |arg|
    return true if attachment.path.ends_with? arg
  end
  false
  end  
end
```

In model/issue, I have:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, allow_destroy: true
validate :suspitious_attachment02

private

def suspitious_attachment02
  attachments.all.each do |attachment|
    if attachment.suspitious_attachment == 1
      errors.add(:attachments, "LOL")
    end 
  end
end
```

Could someone help me? It's possible do this?

Thanks =]

**Solution**

In model/issue.rb, to change

```
def suspitious_attachment02
  attachments.all.each the | attachment |
```

for

```
def suspitious_attachment02
  attachments.each the | attachment |
```

Comment: What's in your controller?

Comment: Hello, well, just doing validations in the model, the controller just CRUD methods.

Comment: Hmm... Okay.  What if you change the `if attachment.suspitious_attachment == 1` to `if true`...  Does it work then?

Comment: What does `attachments.all` return for a particular issue?

Comment: I believe that it lists all the attachments of the current issue. I'll check this.

Comment: \o/ It really was, it worked, it was enough to do:
attachments.each the | attachment |
...
Thank you o /

Comment: No problem. :) Make sure you answer your own question. :)